# Getting remote debugging to work

Tags: visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

I am trying to setup remote debugging to one of my webservers. I have installed Remote Debugger and configured it to my user name on the web server. When I attempt to attach to process in VS 2012, I am able to connect (Remote Debugger on the server shows the log), but when I go to the web site url, my breakpoints are not being hit. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Are the symbols loaded for the DLLs that contain the code where the break point resides?

Comment: The breakpoints are in the ASPX pages, shouldnt the symbols be loaded automatically?

Comment: Not always in remote debugging because the symbols need to be loaded from the debugee machine not the debugger.  Go to the modules page, look for your DLL and check the symbol state

Comment: If you are talking about the Modules page on IIS, my DLLs are not there in the Modules page at all. Do I need to move the PDBs from my local machine to the server somewhere?